# Cannot read database - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

This should be very easy, but I can't createOrReadDatabase without an Exception being thrown

```
 public class DatabaseStuff extends ListActivity {
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;

    public DatabaseStuff() {
        _db = openOrCreateDatabase("Db", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 'eeeeek
    }
```

it throws an exception. I'm totally new to Java, the Logcat seems to say too much for me to understand

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3835)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4450)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18600)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3830)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4450)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18600)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:250)
            at com.lmsites.dave.lifecrymailinglist.MyActivity$DatabaseStuff.<init>(MyActivity.java:109)
            at com.lmsites.dave.lifecrymailinglist.MyActivity.SaveClick(MyActivity.java:71)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3830)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4450)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18600)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need to point out, when I move the methods into the MyActivity class, it works as desired. The issue occurs when I move the function into it's own class.

Could some one help me understand why I can't create this object please?

Comment: The call to `openOrCreateDatabase` causes a NullPointerException. Please post the code of that method.

Comment: Post code of your method 'openOrCreateDatabase()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to create an `Activity` (your class extends `ListActivity`) in the wrong way. You are not supposed to call the constructor of an `Activity` explicitly.

An `Activity` in Android has a life cycle. It is started by the `startActivity` method, which invokes life cycle methods such as `onCreate` to initialize the `Activity`.

When you create an `Activity` instance without calling these methods, it is not initialized properly, which causes methods like `openOrCreateDatabase` to fail.

Comment: super() would anyway be called. No need to explicitly put it.

Comment: I need to do some more work on this, but, I created the database object in the MyActivity and just passed a reference to the construcotr as a work around for now... Thanks